# Getting seed's value from boost random mt19937 generator

Tags: boost, random, seed

I'm using boost::random::mt19937 generator and I need to print it's seed for debug purposes (in order to reproduce my test)
How can I get the seed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to extract what you think of as the seed from mt19937, it's easier set the seed explicitly in both runs for reproducibility.  See boost's [random_demo.cpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/random/example/random_demo.cpp), about 20 lines into the main, for an example of setting the seed. The comment points out that using `std::time(0)` can inadvertently lead to correlated results from two generators if they are seeded in rapid succession based on time.  In your case you actually want identical streams, so you want to set the seed to an explicit value such as `54321` rather than using `std::time(0)`.  Identical seeding produces identical output from the generator.

Comment: "what you think of as the seed from mt19937" - that would be the generator internal state, for completeness

Comment: Tnx
it's pretty annoying that such API doesn't exist but I'll pull myself together :)

Answer (score 1):

Use C++11 features.

```
std::random_device rd;
unsigned long seed = rd();
std::cout << "seed = " << seed << std::endl;

std::mt19937 engine(seed);
```

Comment: I don't think that my old GNU compiler (I think it's 4.4.4) support C++11 features...